# unknown column in 'field list' when columns exist

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, error-handling

I have a database created and it contains this:

```
desc users;
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| UserID       | int(25)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| Username     | varchar(65)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Fname        | varchar(65)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Lname        | varchar(65)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Password     | varchar(32)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Password1    | varchar(32)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| EmailAddress | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

However, when I run this code

```
if($email_exists == false && $Password == $Password1)
            {
                $sql="INSERT INTO users(u_Username, u_Fname, u_Lname, u_EmailAddress, u_Password)
                VALUES('$_POST[$Username]', '$_POST[$Fname]', '$_POST[$Lname]', '$_POST[$EmailAddress]', '$_POST[$Password]')";
                echo "<pre>"; print_r($sql); exit;
                if(!mysqli_query($link, $sql))
                {
                    #$query = mysqli_query($myConnection, $sqlCommand);
                    #die (mysqli_error($myConnection));
                    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($link));               
                }
                header("location: login.php");
            }
```

I get this error:

```
INSERT INTO users(u_Username, u_Fname, u_Lname, u_EmailAddress, u_Password)
                VALUES('', '', '', '', '')
```

What is the error here? I am using php and mysqli. I am new but I'm trying to get my register.php file to accept and add to my database.

**EDIT HERE IS THE FULL CODE**

```
<?php 
session_start();
require_once('connect.php');
require_once "utils.php";

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    //CHECK EMPTY FORM DATA and SANITIZE
    if(!empty($_POST['Username'])&&
       !empty($_POST['Fname'])&& 
       !empty($_POST['Lname'])&& 
       !empty($_POST['EmailAddress'])&& 
       !empty($_POST['Password'])&& 
       !empty($_POST['Password1']))
    {
        $Username = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,htmlentities($_POST['Username']));
        $Fname = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,htmlentities($_POST['Fname']));
        $Lname = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,htmlentities($_POST['Lname']));
        $Password = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,htmlentities($_POST['Password']));
        $Password1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,htmlentities($_POST['Password1']));
        $EmailAddress = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,htmlentities($_POST['EmailAddress']));
    }

    else { header("Location: register.php");exit(); }

        if(isset($EmailAddress) && !empty($EmailAddress) &&
           isset($Password) && !empty($Password))
        {
            $email_exists = false;

            $sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE EmailAddress='$EmailAddress'";

            if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql))
            {
                while($record = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
                {
                    if($record = $EmailAddress)
                    {
                        $email_exists = true;
                    }

                    if($email_exists = true)
                    {
                        echo "<div id='reg_error1'>* The Email Used Already Exists! <br></div>";
                    }
                }
            }

            if($Password != $Password1)
            {
                echo "<div id='reg_error2'>* Your Password Does Not Match!<br></div>";
            }

            if($email_exists == false && $Password == $Password1)
            {
                $sql="INSERT INTO users(Username, Fname, Lname, EmailAddress, Password)
                VALUES('{$_POST['$Username']}', '{$_POST['$Fname']}', '{$_POST['$Lname']}', '{$_POST['$EmailAddress']}', '{$_POST['$Password']}')";
                echo "<pre>"; print_r($sql); exit;
                if(!mysqli_query($link, $sql))
                {
                    #$query = mysqli_query($myConnection, $sqlCommand);
                    #die (mysqli_error($myConnection));
                    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($link));               
                }
                header("location: login.php");
            }
            echo "<hr>";
        }
}
```

Comment: Why `u_Username` when field name is `Username`?

Comment: You've got an unintentional SQL injection vulnerability! You extract all the POST variables into local variables and escape them, but then you don't use the escaped versions in your queries!  Also, are you really storing plaintext passwords?

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql="INSERT INTO users(Username, Fname, Lname, EmailAddress, Password)
                VALUES('{$_POST['$Username']}', '{$_POST['$Fname']}', '{$_POST['$Lname']}', '{$_POST['$EmailAddress']}', '{$_POST['$Password']}')";
```

???

You already extracted the POST vars into those local vars so why are you trying to use them as index arguments on the post array?

```
 $sql="INSERT INTO users(Username, Fname, Lname, EmailAddress, Password)
                VALUES('{$Username'}', '{$Fname}', '{'$Lname}', '{'$EmailAddress'}', '{$Password}')";
```

and if I've got my edit of your code wrong, like quotes in the wrong place, that is becausre I don't write queries like that ever. PDO and prepared statements or stored procedures are what I have been using sonce 2003 and I believe that anyone who does not do it that way is just asking for trouble.

Answer (score 0):

You already store $_POST values in variable like

```
$Username = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,htmlentities($_POST['Username']));
```

So use those variables in query.

```
INSERT INTO users(Username, Fname, Lname, EmailAddress, Password)
            VALUES('$Username'', '$Fname', '$Lname', '$EmailAddress', '$Password')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can insert this when dealing with small tables like this one. This is some what a short hand but works well.

```
$sql="INSERT  INTO users VALUES('', '$_POST[Username]', '$_POST[Fname]', '$_POST[Lname]', '$_POST[EmailAddress]', '$_POST[Password]')";
```

> ''... Not specified because it's automatically generated. 
>   in the table and because the ID is the primary key here, I hope you put it on auto increment and I just left it blank with a value or ''... Not specified because it's automatically generated.

Also, i would discourage you from inserting values from a user directly without doing  any server side validation.